# perf get time elasped with field separator option

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I have a program which parses the output of the linux command perf. It requires the use of option `-x`, (the field separator option. I want to extract `elapsed time` (not `task-time` or `cpu-clock`) using perf. However when I use the `-x` option, the elapsed time is not present in the output and I cannot find a corresponding perf event. Here are the sample outputs

```
perf stat ls
============
 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

          0.934889 task-clock (msec)         #    0.740 CPUs utilized          
                 6 context-switches          #    0.006 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               261 page-faults               #    0.279 M/sec                  
         1,937,910 cycles                    #    2.073 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
         1,616,944 instructions              #    0.83  insns per cycle        
           317,016 branches                  #  339.095 M/sec                  
            12,439 branch-misses             #    3.92% of all branches        

       0.001262625 seconds time elapsed //here we have it
```

Now with field separator option

```
perf stat -x, ls
================
2.359807,task-clock
6,context-switches
0,cpu-migrations
261,page-faults
1863028,cycles
<not supported>,stalled-cycles-frontend
<not supported>,stalled-cycles-backend
1670644,instructions
325047,branches
12251,branch-misses
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: why not change perf sources to print it.

Comment: after looking at the perf source code I see that there's not currently any way to print this when using the field separator.  I wonder why though. I think if someone wants this data in the regular report they might want it in the field separated view.

Comment: @Milind The problem in changing the source code of perf is that, when I have to distribute my code, I have to distribute a custom perf also. But, as Gabriel said, if there is no way in the current perf code, I will try to create a patch file and send to perf maintainers

Comment: In which language is your program, that parses the formated output? I see no other choice than parsing the output of "perf stat ls".

Comment: @amigadev Program is in c++. Parsing directly is not quite uniform, especially when the repeat option and similar are specified. For now, as you suggested, I directly parse without using output formatting, which is kind of bad

Comment: As you are running perf. Why not run some sed stuff with it and get the output of `perf stat ls` formatted as `perf stat -x ls`. Ofcourse with `seconds time elapsed`

Comment: @Milind Yes, it is possible. However the tool I used did not support the normal output. The field separated output is much easier to parse. At the end, I created a custom parser to convert the normal output to field separated output and used this.

Answer (score 1):

```
# perf stat ls 2>&1 >/dev/null | tail -n 2 | sed 's/ \+//' | sed 's/ /,/'

0.002272536,seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with kernel 5.2-rc1, a new event called `duration_time` is exposed by `perf stat`to solve exactly this problem. The value of this event is exactly equal to the `time elapsed` value, but the unit is nanoseconds instead of seconds.